# MSBuild: identity under which a batch script executes

Tags: batch-file, msbuild

I have an MSBuild definition that runs a batch script that attempts to delete some files, but gets "Access is denied" errors. This was working a month ago, the build definition has not changed, and our administrator has given full rights on that folder to the "Build" user.

If I log into the build machine as the user "Build," I am able to run the script without errors. So I thought maybe the script was running as a different user. In the script I added these lines:

```
SET userDomain=%USERDOMAIN%
SET userName=%USERNAME%
```

Which generated this output:

1. 2016-11-18T13:48:19.6308977Z D:\vNextBuildAgent\1_work\b2de54b2\Platform>SET userDomain=Contoso
2. 2016-11-18T13:48:19.6308977Z D:\vNextBuildAgent\1_work\b2de54b2\Platform>SET userName=632766-BUILD$

The domain is right, but I was expecting %USERNAME% to simply be "Build" rather than "632766-BUILD$" as it says.

The name of the build machine is "632766-build" so it looks like the script is running as the local identity of the build machine instead of as the Build service account. How do I specify the identity under which the script executes?

Comment: You have not really specified how it runs when it does it automated.

Comment: @Squashman I don't think I understand what you mean. What information can I add that would be helpful?